# Deciphering script in Python issue

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography

Cheers, I am looking for help with my small Python project. Problem says, that program has to be able to decipher "monoalphabetic substitute cipher", while we have complete database, which words will definetely (at least once) be ciphered.

I have tried to create such a database with words, that are ciphered:

```
lst_sample = []
n = int(input('Number of words in database: '))

for i in range(n):
    x = input()
    lst_sample.append(x)
```

Way, that I am trying to "decipher" is to observe words', let's say structure, where different letter I am assigning numbers based on their presence in word (e.g. feed = 0112, hood = 0112 are the same, because it is combination of three different letters in such a combination). I am using subprogram pattern() for it:

```
def pattern(word):
    nextNum = 0
    letternNums = {}
    wordPattern = []

   for letter in word:
       if letter not in letterNums:
          letternNums[letter] = str(nextNum)     
          nextNum += 1
       wordPattern.append(letterNums[letter])
   return ''.join(wordPattern)
```

Right after, I have made database of ciphered words:

```
lst_en = []

q = input('Insert ciphered words: ')

if q == '':
   print(lst_en)
else:
   lst_en.append(q)
```

With such a databases I could finally create process to deciphering.

```
for i in lst_en:
   for q in lst_sample:
      x = p
      word = i

      if pattern(x) == pattern(word):
         print(x)
         print(word)
         print()
```

If words in database lst_sample have different letter length (e.g. food, car, yellow), there is no problem to assign decrypted words, even when they have the same length, I can sort them based on their different structure: (e.g. puff, sort).

The main problem, which I am not able to solve, comes, when word has the same length and structure (e.g. jane, word).

I have no idea how to solve this problem, while keeping such an script architecture as described above. Is there any way, how that could be solved using another if statement or anything similar? Is there any way, how to solve it with infortmation that words in lst_sample will for sure be in ciphered text?

Thanks for all help!

Comment: Your approach loses sight of the overarching problem. With a simple static substitution cipher, if `x` corresponds to `y` in one word, it will correspond to `y` in all words. The typical approach is to calculate frequency statistics for English (or whichever language you are targeting) and assume that the ciphertext has roughly the same characteristics. Frequency statistics for English would predict that `e` is the most frequent character, `t` is second in rank, `a` is third, followed by `o`, `i`, `n`, etc.

Comment: You might want to do frequency analysis on adjacent characters or entire tokens too (here your current code could actually come in useful) but the key you seek to find is one which unlocks all the words in the text at the same time. (In real-world English you should expect some tokens to not correspond to known dictionary words.)

Comment: For example, if `abc` is the most frequent token in your ciphertext, a good first hypothesis is that it corresponds to "the"; but if that doesn't give useful results for other tokens in the text, fall back to increasingly less likely hypoteses, from "for" and "let" through "fat" and "bin" and eventually to really unlikely ones like "quo" and "pox".

Comment: In your case, probably do a frequency analysis on the dictionary of expected words, rather than all of English, with the slightly silly assumption that each word will occur exactly once if you don't have better information.

Comment: Cheers, thank you for your very useful advice. I have found several ways of solving it, regarding the way you have presented. Even though, the problem I am solving has this very specific instructions, that words in database will definitely be there. If tgere is word "food" it will surely be there.

Comment: I have exact information, that these words in lst_sample will surely be there at least once and nothing else. That is why I chose such a way of solving. Do you think I should use frequency analysis instead? In my opinion this problem do not require such a general way of solving, when I have further info. Thanks!