# Python deciphering project problem update

Tags: python, encryption

This way I want to ask again. I have asked question very similar to this, but I am not sure, whether I described my problem properly. I got very useful response to my problem, but I think this very specific problem could be solved in more simple way.

The problem says, as described in previous question, that we have list of words, that will **for sure** be ciphered. One of the responses mentioned letter frequency analysis, which is a good approach how to solve such a substitution cipher, but I think I have not mentioned properly that, **only** words in lst_sample will be ciphered.

For example if:

```
lst_sample = ['puff','sorting','the']
```

That means, only these words in lst_sample will be there **(not the whole English vocabulary)**, nothing else. I have not mentioned this information properly, that is why I am asking again.

In general I created two lists `lst_en` and `lst_sample` and by using them I compare these words and define which words, based on their common structure and length, are sample text and cipherate to sample text.

Subprogram for definig word structure by numbers:

```
def pattern(word):
    nextNum = 0
    letternNums = {}
    wordPattern = []

   for letter in word:
       if letter not in letterNums:
          letternNums[letter] = str(nextNum)     
          nextNum += 1
       wordPattern.append(letterNums[letter])
   return ''.join(wordPattern)
```

Please find link to original problem bellow, details are mentioned there:

[Deciphering script in Python issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66506047/deciphering-script-in-python-issue)

I know this question has been in some way asked, but this modified instructions change the whole problem conception.

Thank you for your time, any answer regarding porject would be very helpful!

Sincerely,

Marek.

Comment: you are overcomplicating your program. there are really simple methods by which you can achieve better encryption than this. for e.g. use the cryptography module by downloading it pip install cryptography

Comment: I would like to suggest a simple program made with `cryptography`.
just take a look at [this program](https://github.com/vendz/Encryption/blob/master/main.py)